# Image Share is not working all Google Pixel device

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sharing

I am sharing an image from my app using intent. It works fine on all devices but when it comes to Google Pixel 2 XL the image is not loading on skype and gmail. On Gmail, it says: could not attach file. Here is the code snippet

```
 private fun shareImageFromURI(url: String?) {
    Glide.with(this)
        .asBitmap()
        .load(url)
        .into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
            override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
                val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                intent.type = "image/*"
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, getBitmapFromView(resource))
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Image"))
            }

            override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {

            }
        })
}

fun getBitmapFromView(bmp: Bitmap?): Uri? {
    var bmpUri: Uri? = null
    try {
        val file = File(this.externalCacheDir, System.currentTimeMillis().toString() + ".jpg")

        val out = FileOutputStream(file)
        bmp?.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out)
        out.close()
        bmpUri = Uri.fromFile(file)

    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return bmpUri
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

```
        Glide.with(this)
        .asBitmap()
        .load(url)
        .into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
            override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
                val imgBitmapPath = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                    this@ImagesActivity.contentResolver,
                    resource,
                    "eVitalRx_Greetings_" + Calendar.getInstance().getTime(),
                    null
                )
                val imgUri = Uri.parse(imgBitmapPath)
                val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                intent.type = "image/*"
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imgUri)
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
                try {
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, ApplicationClass.languageJson?.downloadDialog?.shareImage))
                }catch (e:Exception){
                    this@ImagesActivity.Toast("Operation Failed")

                }
            }

            override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {

            }
        })
```